# How to override a bad extensions controllers?

Tags: magento-1.8, overrides, routing, router

## Synopsis

I am trying to extend an admin controller of a module, however the `frontend` router and `adminhtml` router share the same `frontname`.  I've tried so many things and none of them are working.

## Extension router example

```
 <admin>
    <routers>
        <AdvancedStock>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>MDN_AdvancedStock</module>
                <frontName>AdvancedStock</frontName>
            </args>
        </AdvancedStock>
    </routers>
</admin>

... snip ...

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <AdvancedStock>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MDN_AdvancedStock</module>
                <frontName>AdvancedStock</frontName>
            </args>
        </AdvancedStock>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

## Attempts

### Attempt 1

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <Vendor_AdvancedStock>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Vendor_AdvancedStock before="MDN_AdvancedStock">Vendor_AdvancedStock</Vendor_AdvancedStock>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </Vendor_AdvancedStock>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

### Attempt 2

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <Vendor_AdvancedStock>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Vendor_AdvancedStock before="MDN_AdvancedStock">Vendor_AdvancedStock</Vendor_AdvancedStock>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </Vendor_AdvancedStock>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

### Attempt 3

This was **attempt 1** and **attempt 2** combined.

### Attempt 4

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <AdvancedStock> <!-- this is the original vendors tag -->
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Vendor_AdvancedStock before="MDN_AdvancedStock">Vendor_AdvancedStock</Vendor_AdvancedStock>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </AdvancedStock>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

---

I have even added the `depends` tag and tried the above attempts with no success.

Comment: which controller that you need to extend? admin side controller or frontend side controller ?

Comment: I need to extend an admin controller, also I noticed `adminhtml` was wrong in my example and so i've corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <advancedstock> <!-- put there the router key of the original module -->
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Vendor_AdvancedStock before="MDN_AdvancedStock">Vendor_AdvancedStock</Vendor_AdvancedStock>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </advancedstock>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Then place your controller inside `Vendor/AdvancedStock/controllers` and make sure it's called the same as the original controller.

Comment: This didn't seem to work; the extension class is: `MDN_AdvancedStock_ProductController` and my class is `Vendor_AdvancedStock_Adminhtml_ProductController` in `./local/Vendor/AdvancedStock/controllers/Adminhtml/ProductController.php`

Comment: @Ash : Most probably this controller would be a frontend controller. Are you sure it is an admin controller ? Can you provide the class that extend this controller here ? lcoation and its name confuses me !

Comment: @Ash. You mean there is a ProductController that is used for admin and it is not inside an `Adminhtml` folder in the extension?

Comment: @Marius that is correct.

Comment: Ok, then try to lose the `_Adminhtml` in the code above and move your controller file also inside `Vendor/AdvancedStock/controllers/ProductController.php`. Damn, that's a badly written extension.

Comment: yes, @Marius is right... wrong declaration of controllers

Comment: @Marius : what about my answer ? is that a necessary one ?

Comment: @Marius haha I know right! Well, that worked thanks :) Also I was being blind too - it's `ProductsController` which I corrected and I followed your suggestion about the `_Adminhtml` namespace

Comment: @Ash. I will edit the answer to remain here for posterity

Comment: @Marius : I think what i have answered here is a continuation of your answer. So it would be useful to otheres if you mention my answer on your answer. What do you think ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt. I don't think that was not really in the scope of the question. As the OP said he considered this 'general knowledge'.

Comment: @Marius : As your wish :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <advancedstock> <!-- assume advancedstock is routers of  MDN_AdvancedStock   -->
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Vendor_AdvancedStock before="MDN_AdvancedStock">Vendor_AdvancedStock_Adminhtml</Vendor_AdvancedStock>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </advancedstock>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

**Vendor_AdvancedStock_Adminhtml is admincontroller  dir of  module Vendor_AdvancedStock**

Comment: This is less informative as to what Marius suggested :S

Comment: This answer is extremely similar as the one Marius posted. Is this a coincidence or is a plain copy of the other answer?

Comment: My answer and Marius answer have posted concurrent  :)

Comment: Not true. They were separated by quite some time, like 15 mins.

Comment: dear mbalparda..  i have put own answer....

Comment: I'm not the one deciding here. Community and everyone who sees this post will take their own conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Ya I was waiting for marius to answer this question. He did it as I expected. I need to mention one more thing along with his answer. You need to call that **"bad controller"** just above your controller definition. That is

File :`Vendor/AdvancedStock/controllers/ProductController.php`

```
<?php    
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','MDN_AdvancedStock').DS.'ProductController.php');
class Vendor_AdvancedStock_ProductController extends MDN_AdvancedStock_ProductController
{
     // some code
}
```

I told so because, as per my knowledge magento will not include the class that you are going to rewrite, if that class stands for a controller.  For block rewrite, helper rewrite you may not require this step. Since magento will do that job for us.

Comment: I sort of excluded this as I assumed people knew - but for anyone here that doesn't will find it useful :)

Comment: Yes you are right. I am sure that, this point will help someone later. So I will request marius to mention my answer also .